# Entity Framework Code First's code generation creates both int-based FK and complex object, why?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to better understand the reasoning behind some of the choices made via Reverse Engineer Code First.

This the the schema - shows I have FK to both a User and to an Affiliate.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
    [ID]                  INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [idUser]              INT             NOT NULL,
    [orderDate]           SMALLDATETIME   NOT NULL,
    [total]               MONEY           NOT NULL,
    [idAffiliate]         INT             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_cartHead] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Affiliates] FOREIGN KEY ([idAffiliate]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Affiliates] ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([idUser]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([ID])
);
```

Here's RE's generation:

```
...
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int idUser { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime orderDate { get; set; }
        public decimal total { get; set; }
        public int idAffiliate { get; set; }
        public virtual Affiliate Affiliate { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrdersRow> OrdersRows { get; set; }
```

OrderMap.cs

```
    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("Orders");
    this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
    this.Property(t => t.idUser).HasColumnName("idUser");
    this.Property(t => t.orderDate).HasColumnName("orderDate");
    this.Property(t => t.total).HasColumnName("total");
    this.Property(t => t.initiatedBy).HasColumnName("initiatedBy");
    this.Property(t => t.idAffiliate).HasColumnName("idAffiliate");

    // Relationships
    this.HasRequired(t => t.Affiliate)
        .WithMany(t => t.Orders)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.idAffiliate);
    this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
        .WithMany(t => t.Orders)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.idUser);
```

What I'm curious about is what looks like duplication - the idAffiliate is functionally the same as the complex object - Affiliate. Same for idUser -> User.

Is there a reason the class would want both?

[Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

thx

Comment: See a good discussion about this: http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Entity Framework there are two ways of representing foreign keys, on is the actual ID and the other is a concept called Navigation Properties. Navigation properties allow you to essentially join in additional data referenced by the foreign key.

Navigation properties are a great way of coding for joined data as they allow simple and readable code for entity references. It also fits with the way C# does objects.

You may well want both of these in your model for performance reasons. If you use the Navigation property to see if your Order has an Affiliate (or if it has an Affiliate with a specific ID) this will require a join on the Affiliate table.

You could achieve the same thing without using a Join in SQL by simply looking at the FK Id.

Answer (score 1):

One good reason for having the fk id properties is you can easily change them without needing to load any extra objects in memory.

```
MyObj.Fkid = 6;
```

Instead of

```
MyObj.FkObj = fkobject;
```